# Securing rest calls within 2 application

Tags: spring, spring-security, resteasy

Let consider the application as  App-A and App-B . App-A calls some rest calls in App-B and vice versa. I am using Spring 3.0 , Resteasy . How can i secure the rest call in this senario ?. Any help , example or idea would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First grant the authorization key for server A from B. Now make request to server B from Server A along with authorization key in the request header. Now validate that authorization key in server B to get confirmation either request came from known server or not. if that key in request header and Authorization key stored for server A in Server B are same then you confirm request is valid.

Comment: Thanks.Do you have any sample or working links for this